# Involutions on power series $\mathbb{C}[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]]$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

For the ring of formal power series $\mathbb{C}[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]]$ over complex numbers,
is it true that any automorphism of order $2$ is after change of co-ordinates
given by $X_i\mapsto  \pm  X_i$?

Comment: Yes, and one has similarly that for any algebraically closed field $k$ and finite abelian group $G$ of order not divisible by ${\rm{char}}(k)$ that any $G$-action on the $k$-algebra $k[\![x_1,\dots,x_n]\!]$ is given by $g.x_i = \chi_i(g)x_i$ for some characters $\chi_i:G \rightarrow k^{\times}$ after a suitable formal change of coordinates.  For a proof, see Lemma 3.3 of http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1992__81_3/CM_1992__81_3_291_0/CM_1992__81_3_291_0.pdf (which gives a version replacing $k$ with any complete local noetherian ring in which $\#G$ is a unit, with $G$ any finite group).

Comment: nfdc23 has already answered this positively. You should also be able to check it by hand. Let $R$ be the power series ring. By linear algebra, one gets a basis of $m/m^2$ diagonalizing the action, and now lift these generators to $R/m^N$ as $N\to \infty$. I'm guessing this would be the same argument as above.

Comment: @DonuArapura: Yes, that is also exactly the method used in Edixhoven's paper that I linked above (except that Edixhoven worked over a complete local noetherian ring and so spoke in terms of merely "linearizing" the action rather than diagonalization, the latter suitable just for abelian $G$ and algebraically closed $k$).

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question with precise reference.

Comment: Non-PDF version of @nfdc23 's link:  http://numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=CM_1992__81_3_291_0 .

Comment: @nfdc23, please, there is a problem with the link.

Comment: Hmm, it seems both my original link and the one by @LSpice are now broken. It is the 3rd volume in issue #81 of Compositio Math (in 1992). The "stable" URL according to Numdam is http://numdam.org/item/CM_1992__81_3_291_0  Let's see if it is really stable (or just semi-stable, or worse).

Comment: @nfdc23, wow, Numdam is a wonderful site, but they sure need to learn that "[cool URIs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)"!

Comment: @user237522: I have now included an updated link that will hopefully not break in the future, in my most recent comment above.

Comment: @nfdc23, great, thank you very much!

Comment: @LSpice, nfdc23, DonuArapura: It would be great if one of you will explain what is exactly meant by "formal change of coordinates"; do you mean that $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)$ is an example of a formal change of coordinates? I hope that the answer is yes, since such a map is needed in order to make the involution $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)$ of the form $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$.

Comment: @DipendraPrasad, please, do you mean that, for example when $n=2$, an involution (before change of coordinates) is of one of the following forms: (1) $(x,y) \mapsto (\pm x+H_1, \pm y)$; (2) $(x,y) \mapsto (\pm x, \pm y + H_2)$;  (3) $(x,y) \mapsto (\pm y+H_3, \pm x)$; (4) $(x,y) \mapsto (\pm y, \pm x + H_4)$, where $H_1,H_4 \in k[[y]]$, $H_2,H_3 \in k[[x]]$ with every $H_i$ having zero constant term (one has to be careful about the sigh $\pm$ of $x$ and $y$, but I will not elaborate on this now). Am I missing something? Is it true that the $H_i$'s are of one variable only? Thank you very much!

Comment: @nfdc23, (1) "a formal change of coordinates" = any automorphism? Or (2) a formal change of coordinates means an automorphism of some special form as I suggested in the above comment? (According to Lemma 3.3 of the above link, it seems that (1) is true, so it can be any automorphism).

Comment: @DonuArapura, nfdc23, please, what do you think about the comments in the related question  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242588/involutions-on-mathbbcx-y#comment4611559_2242588, and what about the second question there? Thank you very much!